# event binding in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a viewModel with an array of answerGroup objects.  When the feedback property of one of the answerGroup objects is updated I want to save the updated object to my database by passing it via ajax to my ASP.Net MVC app.

Instead of having a typical save button or link, I want the object to be passed to the Ajax call when the object's property has been updated.  I thought I could do this by binding to the change event of the textarea element but if I do this the ajax function is called but the underlying answerGroup object's feedback property is not updated.

I'm using Knockout 1.2.1.  Below is the JavaScript code, I haven't included the HTML.

Am I going about this the wrong way or is it just that my syntax for the knockout.js event binding is incorrect?

```
<script>
var viewModel = {}

$(function () {
    viewModel.scenarioId = ko.observable($("#Scenario_ScenarioID").val());
    viewModel.answerGroups = ko.observableArray([]);
    viewModel.addGroup = function (answerGroup) {

        // add item to beginning of array
        this.answerGroups.unshift(answerGroup);
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

function answerGroup() {
    this.id = ko.observable();
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.feedback = ko.observable();

    // the groups feedback has been updated so save
    // these details back to the server
    this.updateGroup = function (event) {

      // javascript api library that is an ajax function.
      // this works without a problem.
      api.updateAnswerGroup({
        success: function (result) {
            alert("saved!");
        },
        error: function (e) {
           alert("error!");
        },
        data: "answerGroupId=" + this.id + "&feedback=" + this.feedback
      });

      return true;
    };
}
</script>

<script id="answerGroupsTemplate" type="text/html">
  <div>
    <h4><a href='#'>${ $data.name }</h4>
    <div>
       <textarea cols="100" rows="2" data-bind="event: { text: feedback, change: updateGroup }">
       </textarea>                  
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: maybe i am lazy but i think its too much code. which part is the relevant part

Comment: Ibu - all of it is relevant, I've not included the irrelavant parts.

Comment: The updateGroup function is called but the underlying value of the feedback property is not updated.  I need the feedback property to update and then the updateGroup function to be called so I can pass the value of this property back to the server.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The typical way to handle this in Knockout is to do a manual subscription on the observable that you want to react to changes on.

So, you would do something like:

```
function answerGroup() {
    this.id = ko.observable();
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.feedback = ko.observable();

    this.feedback.subscribe(function (newValue) {
       //run your update code here
    }, this);
}
```

The second parameter to the subscribe function controls the context ("this") when the function runs.

The nice part about a subscription like this is that it will fire when the observable is changed programmatically or changed based on a binding in your UI.

Brief docs on it here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables

I had a post that included info on using manual subscriptions [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/reacting-to-changes-in-knockoutjs.html) too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've read the docs on the knockout.js website regarding subscriptions, custom bindings etc, but your post put it all in context for me.  Nice work.  Now, I've added the subscribe piece of code and inserted an alert inside the function but it's not firing.  Any ideas?

Comment: If I add a subscription to the viewModel however it does fire, i.e.  viewModel.answerGroups.subscribe(function (newValue) { alert(newValue); }, this);

Comment: What does your binding look like against the feedback observable?  Are you using the value binding?

Comment: I changed it yes, to use the value binding only - <textarea cols="100" rows="2" data-bind="value: feedback"></textarea>

Comment: Maybe, you could try to reproduce based on this fiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Sm65u/

Comment: I've reproduced it and it has the same issue, i.e. the subscribe function isn't firing http://jsfiddle.net/Robini/Sm65u/5/  Fingers crossed you can see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Hello- When you set an observable, you will need to set it like this:
`myObservable(myValue)` rather than `myObservable = myValue`.  Otherwise, you are resetting the variable to `myValue` rather than setting the observable to that value.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Sm65u/6/

Comment: Thanks Ryan! You're right, I changed the way I was setting properties and everything works now.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this for me.  I knew I must have been doing something silly, but I just couldn't see the issue.

Comment: Happens to everyone.  Sometimes just having another set of eyes on it helps!

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to subscribe to the observable like how RP Niemeyer describes, but sometime you need to attach to an event and not the observable.  Therefore you can use the "event" binding.  The documentation doesn't include the "change" event, but I have tried it with version v2.0.0rc and it works:

```
<input data-bind="value: viewModel.MyProperty, event: { change: viewModel.MyPropertyChanged } />
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html